# Having Issue Binding Team Foundation Server Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

So I connected to a project via myproject.visualstudio.com, I then clicked "Soure Control Explorer":
[image]

Then I clicked "Get Latest Version":

[image]

This download the source code and correctly mapped a local directory for me. But my project is not under source control in the solution explorer, if I right click on the solution I see:
[image]

Which I click and then see error:
[image]

After reaching this error on the internet I go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control to rebind:

[image]

And I see:
[image]

In this screenshot I clicked Bind for the sln. But it makes checkout to bind to the server:
[image]

I just want Visual Studio integrated solution explorer Get Latest and Checkin functions, I got latest from TFS and do not understand what the big deal is with getting Visual Studio 2012 to understand.

Comment: That looks right so far, can you just carry on with Binding all the Project Files and the Solution, the "Check out" on bind is normal.

Comment: I can but I don't want to checkout anything, normally I just connect to aproject.visualstudio.com and viola I have integrated TFS menu items when right clicking the sln or a project or a file. I can get latest or commit changes if I have any, if I continue, I feel like I am checkiing out all files in the project which I do not want to do. I just want a working version and want to track diff with repository and commit stable diffs.

Comment: TFVC needs "Bindings" in the CSProj and SLN files. This is usually 4 Elements in each the CSProj and a new GlobalSection in the SLN file. Without the SLN at least, VS won't play. I have no idea why, it shouldn't be needed with Local workspaces.

Comment: Ya the guy that setup this project in TFS is too smart for his own good, he initially had this cmd files you would run to diffs with the repository that would open up Winmerge. He then gave me a TFS online account because I was like, come on dude let's keep this aspect simple.

Comment: Perhaps it will only check out the CSProj and SLN files if I continue, I just would had for this to kick of a process of checking out every single file.

Comment: No, it will only checkout the SLN, a vspcc file (no idea what that one is, I just keep mine) and the CSProj's. It's a one off task, once it's done, you just use it.

Comment: Go ahead and provide a simple answer that I should just continue on with the Binding and check out the CSproj and SLN files for success and I will mark correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you are on the right track. If you continue and Check-Out the SLN file it will add the bindings to the SLN and csproj files. These are some extra properties in the csproj file and a new GlobalSection in the SLN file. With these Visual Studio will be fully aware of TFS and provide status icons in File Explorer and all the other goodness.